# Restarting SQL service on primary causes failover of AG to secondary even when the setting says that it must try a reboot prior to failover

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019, clustering

In WSFC resource properties there is a config to attempt a restart prior to failover.

For testing purpose, on primary node (Node1) I restarted the sql service (from sql configuration manager), and the SQL server has failed-over to the secondary node (Node2) automatically.

Shouldn't it have attempted a restart of Node1 prior to failing over to Node2?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps "I restarted the sql service" does not qualify as a **failure**? Did you try killing the SQL Service process instead?

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't it have attempted a restart of Node1 prior to failing over to Node2?

How do you know it didn't? 1 restart attempt 0.5 seconds after the fault. Not exactly exhaustive. Did you look at the cluster logs? What did they say?

This is behaving as it should.

Comment: Well the cluster has role. The role has resource which is the listener. So you mean it will restart the listener? I'm so confused.

Comment: If the listener is what failed, then yes. However it wasn't the listener that failed, it was the AG which is also a resource. The AG resource was restarted, but this won't do anything because the SQL instance is shut down.

Comment: What does AG resource restart mean? Can an AG be restarted? This is new to me. Sql instance was never shut down why do you say that please?

Comment: You have, in your post, that you restarted SQL - it was down for a period of time. Your questions turn into "and then" comment answers. If you have other questions, post them, please do not "and then" answered questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a normal reaction, until the retry attempts the show must go on!

You restarted the primary so the AG has to change immediately to one of the secondaries.

Based on your settings I think the following process will happen after a failover:

1. Primary failover
2. One of the secondaries takes the primary's place (**immediately**)
3. Try to restart the "old" primary which will be a
   secondary after the service restarted successfully - it can start at the same time as 2. but there is no time to wait for the result of the first restart attempt.

Try to stop the service (on primary) not restart and check what happens. - After a successful automatic restart attempt, it should be a secondary

> Shouldn't it have attempted an automatic restart of Node1 prior to failing over to Node2?

**No.**
Just think about it, a restart in a (best-case scenario too) should take more time than a failover to one of the replicas. - This is not an SQL Server AG specific idea, this is how every OLTP system HA must work in the world. There is no time to wait for restarts there must be always at least one secondary ready to be primary.